# Hot reloading properties in a Python Flask/Django app

Tags: python, flask

Gurus, Wizards, Geeks

I am tasked with providing Python Flask apps (*more generally, webapps written in python*) a way to reload properties on the fly.

Specifically, my team and I currently deploy python apps with a `{env}.properties` file that contains various environment specific configurations in a key value format (yaml for instance). Ideally, these properties are reloaded by the app when changed. Suppose a secondary application existed that updates the previously mentioned `{env}.properties` file, the application should ALSO be able to read and use new values.

Currently, we read the `{env}.properties` at startup and the values are accessed via functions stored in a `context.py`. I could write a function that could periodically update the variables. Before starting an endeavor like this, I thought I would consult the collective to see if someone else has solved this for Django or Flask projects (as it seems like a reasonable request for feature flags, etc).

Answer (score 1):

One such pattern is the WSGI application factory pattern.

In short, you define a function that instantiates the application object. This pattern works with all WSGI-based frameworks.

The Flask docs explain [application factories](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appfactories/#application-factories) pretty well.

This allows you to define the application dynamically on-the-fly, without the need to redeploy or deploy many configurations of an application. You can change just about anything about the app this way, including configuration, routes, middlewares, and more.

A simple example of this would be something like:

```py
def get_settings(env):
    """get the (current, updated) application settings"""
    ...
    return settings

def create_app(env: str):
    if env not in ('dev', 'staging', 'production'):
        raise ValueError(f'{env} is not a valid environment')
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.update(get_settings(env))
    return app
```

Then, you could set `FLASK_APP` environment variable to something like `"myapp:create_app('dev')"` and that would do it. This is also the same way you could specify this for servers like `gunicorn`.

The `get_settings` function should be written to return the newest settings. It could even do something like retrieve settings from an external source like S3, a config service, or anything.